# Caching user data in asp.net application

Tags: asp.net, caching

What's the best way to cache web site user data in asp.net 4.0?

I have a table of user settings that track all kinds of user or session specific stuff like the state of UI elements (open/closed), preferences, whether some dialog has been dismissed, and so on. Since these don't change very often (for each user, anyway) but are looked up frequently it seems sensible to cache them. What's the best way? These are the options I've identified...

1. Store them in `HttpContext.Current.Session` directly (e.g. `Session["setting_name"]`)
2. Store them in `HttpContext.Current.Cache`
3. Use a global static dictionary, e.g. `static ConcurrentDictionary<string,string>` where the key is a unique userID + setting name value
4. Store a dictionary object for each session in `Session` or `Cache`

What's the most sensible way to do this? How does `Session` differ from `Cache` from a practical standpoint? Would it ever make sense to store a dictionary as a single session/cache object versus just adding lots of values directly? I would think lookups might be faster, but updates would be slower since I'd have to re-store the entire dictionary when it changed.

What problems or benefits might there be to using a global static cache? Seems like this would be the fastest, but I'd have to manage the size. I could just flush it periodically if it hits a certain size, or keep a cross reference queue and remove things oldest first when it gets to a certain size. Does this make any sense or is it just trying too hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Session` may end up being stored out-of-process or in a database, which can make retrieving it expensive.  You would likely be using a session database if your application is to be hosted in a server farm, as opposed to a single server.  A server farm provides improved scalability and reliability, and it's often a common deployment scenario.  Have you thought about that?

Also, when you use `Session` not in-process, it ends up getting *serialized* to be sent out-of-process or to a database, and *deserialized* when retrieved, and you are *effectively* doing what you describe above:

> ...  *updates would be slower since I'd have
>   to re-store the entire dictionary when
>   it changed.* ...

.. since, even if you use individual session keys, the entire `Session` object for a user is serialized and deserialized together (all at once).

Whereas, `Cache` would be **in memory** on a particular server in the farm, and therefore much more efficient than going out of process or to the database.  However, something in cache on one server might not be in cache on another.  So if a user's subsequent request is directed to another server in the farm, the cache on that server might not yet hold any of the user's items.

Nevertheless, I'd suggest you use `Cache` if you're caching for performance reasons.

*p.s. Yes, you're trying too hard.  Don't reinvent the wheel unless you **really** need to. :-)*

Comment: Server farm is a possibility (though site's hosted in-house now on a single instance) - and there aren't really any consequences if something cached on one server becomes unavailable on another (it just looks it up from the database again). Sounds like the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

might be better to put your information into memcached for scalability